# PHP to detect string of subfolder and parse the string

Tags: php, string

So I have a simple variable that detects my /en/ or /sp/ sub folders in my site and puts those letters into my html class - right now I am just saying if the page isnt intro than echo 'en', how can I detect whether or not $page contains 'en', or 'sp' - basically on the english part of my site I want `<html class="home en"` and the spanish side `<html class="home sp"`

```
$page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
$page = str_replace('/', '', $page); 
$page = str_replace('.php', '', $page); 
$page = str_replace('?s=', '', $page);
$page = str_replace('en', '', $page);
$page = str_replace('sp', '', $page);
$page = $page ? $page : 'intro';

<html class="<?php echo $page ; if($page !== 'intro')echo ' en'; ?>">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect this with **strpos** or **stripos** function. More about it in the PHP manual: http://si.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

```
$isSpanish = stripos ($page, "/sp/");

if ($isSpanish !== FALSE)
{
    // Logic here
}
```